# Mobile photography and color chart

Tags: product-photography, color-correction, iphone, still-life, mobile

I have read online that to get colors right in photo you need to use color chart.

I have searched online, but have not found any information if color chart is used(should be used) also when taking pictures with mobile (more specifically still life photography, product photography).

If I use mobile, how can I be sure that colors could be right in end result? (printed books, e-commerce website ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process of using color charts require to take photos in RAW. This is because of few factors:

1. Using charts you can tune white balance of the photo. And in JPG you
   have already set/incorporated the white balance.
2. To get precise colors you will need more information than JPG can
   provide (more than 8 bits per color).

The process of using color charts include taking photo of the chart, located on the same place as object, under the same lighting conditions. Then do take the photos. Then in postprocessing create profile (from 1st photo) for this particular lighting situation and apply this profile to the rest of the photo.

I am not sure the device you mention in tags to support RAW shooting, so if you use exactly such device (IMHO) you can get precise colors only if you can shoot RAW.

Comment: it is correct that a color chart can be used for the correct white balance but for this trivial task mostly a greycard with a defined grey value is used. with the chart you tune all relevant colors to get the most accurate color representation but this has no real use with the limited data of a jpg. and its for the most usecases (like stil life and product photography) over the top and a correct white balance would be enough.

Comment: By "device in tags", do you mean "iPhone"? Because one can use the Lightroom mobile app to shoot in RAW on iPhone and many (most? all?) Android phones.

Comment: @mattdm, yes, I mean iPhone. Never use such device so have no info. About android: NO, not all android devices can shoot RAW, personal experience with Sony XA Ultra